# Mascara para CNPJ em Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Eu estou tentando colocar uma mascara em uma string que é um CNPJ.
Recebo uma string com tamanho 14 e tentei dessa forma colocar a mascara:

```
 NSString *cnpj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@/%@-%@", 
 self.codCnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(11, 2)], 
 [self.codCnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 3)], 
 [self.codCnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 3)],     
 [self.codCnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(1, 4)],
 [self.codCnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)]];
```

Bem, isso não está dando nem um pouco certo.. Alguns valores se repetem e outros não são mostrados.
Alguem tem alguma sugestão de melhoria ou uma forma mais simples de fazer isso?

Comment: vou responder aqui no comentário pois não disponho de muito tempo para uma resposta gigante como a galera aqui "exige". Se responder com algo curto geralmente vem um bando de troll negativar.. então, sem mais delongas: https://github.com/fjcaetano/NSStringMask  No google busquei por "objective c input mask"

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta @DanielOmine . Como era somente essa situação que ia precisar ter uma mascara, acabei encontrando uma outra solução usando só o substringWithRange mesmo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou me responder porque encontrei uma forma só usando substring mesmo. O que estava errando era a ordem dos indices. Então segue a minha solução:

```
NSString *finalCnpj = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@.%@/%@-%@", 
[self.cnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, 2)], 
[self.cnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, 3)], 
[self.cnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(5, 3)], 
[self.cnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(8, 4)], 
[self.cnpj substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(12, 2)]];
```